# Ajax-данные пропадают после нажатия f5 oder ctrl+f5

Tags: ajax, javascript

т.е. есть сайтик, где все странички-разделы - это подгружаемые AJAXом хтмл-файлики, но вот проблема если открыть любой раздел сайта и после обновить страницу то увидим главную страницу, и это логично, но как выйти из такой ситуации

какими способами можно сохранять подгруженные AJAXом данные после обновления страницы?

Answer (score 1):

Меняйте адрес в адресной строке при помощи `window.history.pushState`

Вот статья по этому поводу: [HTML5: Changing the browser-URL without refreshing page](http://spoiledmilk.com/blog/html5-changing-the-browser-url-without-refreshing-page/).

Вот ещё хороший пример кода, как раз для вашего случая: [Modify the URL without reloading the page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3354511/276994).

Comment: спасибо, но мне нужно чтобы после нажатия клавиш f5илиCTRL+f5 страница не теряла то что было, подгружено Ajaxом.
Если я меняю URL и юзаю window.history, тогда при нажатии f5 мой URL обрабатывается веб-сервером, т.е. он ищет файл contacts.* при URL == mysite.com/contacts и если не находит возвращает 404, а если название файла и алиас совпадают, то загружает содержимое это файла

Comment: афтар жги дальше! Вчитайся в то что тебе написали!

Comment: "БЕЗ перезагрузки страницы", т.е. это все будет работать, до того как я нажму F5 потом будет 404, потому что УРЛ составлен у клиента и сервер про него ничего не знает.

Comment: @deniz: ну так составьте URL, который будет понятен серверу, делов-то!

Answer (score 0):

Данные можешь хранить в `sessionStorage` подробнее можешь почитать [тут](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) и [тут](http://habrahabr.ru/search/?q=%5Bsessionstorage%5D&target_type=posts). Ещё как вариант предлогаю каждый раз загружать ajax данные. Для этого необходимо помечать урл хэшем типа http://site/#post/123, потом при следующей загрузке страницы загружать данные с `window.location.hash`. С помощью **jQuery** это выглядит примерно так:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    url = window.location.hash.substr(1) //убираем символ #
    $("#content").load(url) //загружаем данные аяксом в контейнер #content
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Никак. После того как пользователь обновил страницу, браузер попытается загрузить всё по-новой (ну или вытащить из кеша).

Как верно подсказали, ты можешь модифицировать url в адресной строке. Тогда нажав обновить страница будет загружена с этого нового адреса. Но тогда нужно следить чтобы контент который подгружаешь динамически и который запрашивается по-новой совпадал.

Comment: пришлось юзать localStorage и отказаться от изменения УРЛа, потому что htaccess не могу использовать.